# Is it an anti-pattern to have colors with opacity?

Tags: css, colors

I think that having colors with opacity in design is an anti-pattern because this color might look different if parent's background color changes but I keep seeing people making UI in Figma with such colors.

For example, imagine if we have a black circle, on hover we want it to change its bg color to grayish, instead of just picking suitable gray color, e.g. `#414141` people take black color and add 70% opacity, e.g. `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)`

If I put under this grayish circle different colored rectangles then the one with opacity looks different under each color, on the other hand the one without opacity looks the same:

[image]

If I see in design a color with opacity I always use an eyedropper to pick its "pure" color from the one with opacity.

**Do you guys agree that it's always better to use colors without opacity or there're cases where it's better to apply opacity?**

Answer (score 1):

This question is opinionated but I will try to analyse it objectively. One of the benefits of having color with `opacity` is exactly what you have mentioned, to allow it to "add" / stack to the background. Sometimes having it is an easy way to make the contrast better.

For example, you have a body text color of `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)`, this probably looks okay in a pure white background. However, when it is used it a slightly grey-ish background (eg. `#f5f5f5`), the text contrast suddenly become less obvious because the background color is darker now. However, having a color with alpha values let it stack and ensures the text color is even darker on different shades of background.

It is also particularly useful in shadow, having a bit of opacity allows it to blend into the background better instead of it looking a bit too unique / separated from the background.

I also find an interesting discussion about this in UX StackExchange: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/126067/why-define-opaque-color-as-partially-transparent

Comment: *"This question is opinionated"* Then it should be closed and not answered. And pure UX question aren't on-topic either.